# Div retrieved by JavaScript not showing up in source code

Tags: javascript, html, view-source-chart

I am retrieving a div like so:

```
window.onload=  function get_all(){
  function get_header(){
        $('#main_header').load('/Head_footer.php #head_main');
    }

    $(function() {
        get_header();
    }); };
```

However the source code is not show what is in the div, but it is shown properly in the webpage.

This is what the source code shows:

```
 <div id="main_header"><script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=  function get_all(){
      function get_header(){
            $('#main_header').load('/Head_footer.php #head_main');
        }
        $(function() {
            get_header();
        });
}; </script>
    </div>
```

What I want is that the source code shows what is in the div. Is there a way to do that? Any help welcome.

The reason why I ask this is because google doesn't read the mark up of the structured data within this div. As it is not shown in the source code

Comment: The source doesn't contain the DIV. It is being loaded via Head_footer.php. If you load the page in Google Chrome, you can right click and "inspect element" which should show you the contents of the loaded page.

Comment: You are adding div after window gets load. So, your source code is ready and after that you are adding a div. So, it is not in source code.

Comment: @Gokul Shinde, do you know if there is there a way to load it before window load.

Comment: sure You have #head_main in your dom?

Comment: @fedeghe I'm sorry not sure what you mean, it is loaded from a different page

Comment: @Ria ... sorry, u're right. The `load` func is really an aberration, thx to God I never had to read [this](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

In view source you can only see the things which are already existed. You cannot see dynamic content but if you want to inspect those dynamic content then use Developer tools of your browser

For the Firefox Right click on page and select Inspect Element option

Comment: before right click to inspect element in FF, need to install firebug.

Comment: @GokulShinde :  By default Firefox provides **Inspect Element (Q)**  option. If you will install firebug then there will be last option **Inspect Element with Firebug**